# asp.net core DB scaffolding

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-cli

I am getting an error trying to scaffold DBcontext using shell commands according to "Scaffold the model" section from asp.net tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1). The command:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m MyClass -dc MyContext -udl
                                      -outDir Pages\MyClass --referenceScriptLibraries
```

fails with error CS0234 complaining about 'Hosting' type or namespace.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: did you run `dotnet restore` before you ran this command?

Comment: yes a few times for sure :)

Comment: there is an open issue on github with a preview version that someone claims works. https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/771.

Comment: thank you, its now work. I spent whole day in trying to understand the issue.